# Is it possible to avoid package and import statement?

Tags: java, import, package

So I learned that if I have two packages say: one default package and one another package "com.projectjava" which contains a class say, MyClass.java then I need to use a package statement inside it:

```
package com.projectjava;

public class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

And, in default package where the main function I need an `import` statement:

```
import com.projectjava.*;

public class MyClassTest {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to avoid both the import and package statement and use full declaration syntax such as `com.projectjava.MyClassTest`? Is the package statement a requirement?

Comment: Yes, it's legal.  In fact, it's *required* if you have two classes from different packages with the same name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "avoid the package statement". If you want your class to be in a package, then the package statement is required. If you don't put a package statement, then your class is in the default package. But that's very, very bad practice. And you'll have all sorts of problems if you do that (like not being able to use that class in other classes that are in packages, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package` is mandatory if your class finds itself in a package other than the `default package`

---

If you don't want to use `import` you may simply use the fully-qualified name of the class like for example   `java.util.regex.Pattern`

Comment: So, I guess the package statement tells the compiler which package the file belongs to, if I am right?

Comment: Indeed that's it :)

Answer (score 1):

The package statement is required, the import statement is usually recommended but not required.

If you don't use an import statement you have to use the fully qualified name of the class you're using:

```
public class MyClassTest {

   public void foo() {
       com.projectjava.MyClass myClassInstance = new com.projectjava.MyClass(...) 
   }

}
```